# Why won't my leopard gecko eat?

Tags: leopard-geckos, geckos

My leopard gecko, Marley is over a year old and we have had him since he was a baby. From the day we brought him home he would eat every time we fed him and was very healthy. We recently moved, 5 days ago. He was in a 40 gallon tank (yes, very spoiled) and when we moved we changed him to a 20 gallon enclosure for practical reasons. He ate the night we moved. The following day, he had runny poop and the day after that, dry white poop which did not look normal. Yesterday, he pooped normally which made me happy but he still hasn't eaten. His tail looks the same, thick and healthy and he is moving about his enclosure. So his behavior is normal, but no eating at all. I have tried everything i think of. I dont know what to do. I spoke with a reptile store over the phone, and she said not to worry but i cant help it. From some angles, his tail looks a bit ashy which makes me believe he may shed but not anytime soon. I am asking for some advice, i am desparate to keep this little guy healthy but i dont want to rush to a vet far away if there is information people can help me with online. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Pets Stack Exchange! We have some other questions about this kind of thing: [Gecko Won't Eat](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/17095/gecko-wont-eat) and [Baby Leopard Gecko won't eat](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/16925/baby-leopard-gecko-wont-eat). Please check these out and let me know if they solve your problem.